# react-native calender picker in dialog in ios

Tags: ios, datepicker, react-native

In `react-native-ios`, I am using `react-native-datepicker` for selecting date from calender. 
For this, I am using following link:
[Date Picker in react-native-ios](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)

I am adding following code in my render method:

```
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
   <TouchableOpacity
     style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}
     onPress={() => this.openCalender()}>

     <DatePicker
       style={{width: 150}}
       date={this.state.date}
       mode="date"
       placeholder="Date"
       format="YYYY-MM-DD"
       minDate="2015-01-01"
       maxDate="2025-12-01"
       confirmBtnText="Confirm"
       cancelBtnText="Cancel"
       iconSource={require('./assets/cal.png')}
       onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date});}}
     />
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

but I want to add this date picker in dialog. What will be the way for implementing that in `react-native-ios`.

I want to put Date picker on NavBar Right button click.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/pandiaraj44/react-native-datepicker-dialog for easy implementation of date-picker for both android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library : https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

It works great and cross-platform too.

Comment: Hey, I have also mentioned same link for `date picker`. But I want Date Picker on right side of `Navigation bar`

Comment: Well, your link is not working. I don't understand what you mean by right side of navbar. Can you post a preview image?

Comment: Yes. I understood that. But what exactly is not working for you here?

Comment: I want to put `Datepicker` on `NavBar`,  `Right button` click.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your code above will not work unless you move the `<DatePicker/>` outside the `<TouchableOpacity/>`. Once you move that out it should open up the picker as expected by the package.